# Rails 3 app - problem with saving integer to column with data type int(11)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, integer

I have following a structure of MySQL table:

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| reg        | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descr      | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And with this way I am saving data to my database:

```
 @saving = Table.new(:reg => 1234, :descr => params[:descr]).save
```

And my problem is - I don't know how it is possible, but this query does not save the number to column "reg". I am getting this error

> `Mysql2::Error: Column 'reg' cannot be null: INSERT INTO`name_of_table`(`updated_at`,`descr`,`reg`,`created_at`) VALUES ('2011-06-06 20:40:43', 'description of man', NULL, '2011-06-06 20:40:43')`

I worked a lot with PHP and MySQL database, but this error I never got...
Where's the problem?

Comment: In your `Table` model, do you have `attr_accessible` somewhere? If so, add `:ref` to it.

Comment: If I rename [b]reg[/b] to something else, still the same error. In my model is only this:
[b]attr_accessible :id, :reg_id(--renamed from reg), :descr[/b]

Comment: I found that the problem is with all column (also in other tables) types except integer id (AUTO_INCREMENT) --> it's really weird, I have no idea what could be wrong

Comment: Sounds like the models are confused about the structure of the tables.  Have you tried restarting the web server (to get the easy fixes out of the way first)?

Comment: I tried to restart MySQL server and Rails server too, but unfortunately still the problem alive... it already make me crazy

Comment: I tried mysql> INSERT INTO shops SET reg_id=8; --> and this works, so I have no idea, what coudl be wrong in my app :/

Comment: Have you tried setting the :reg on the object not in mass assignment? `Tablew.reg = 1234` then save it. Remember :reg has to be on attr_accessible if you want to mass assign it.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

if you look at your schema, it says the default for :reg is NULL, **and** that it can not be NULL -- that might cause the problem you see

can you change the schema to allow :reg to be NULL and try again?